# Facebook OAuth2 with DotNetOpenAuth under MVC3

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate on FB (and Twitter, also) using OAuth.  Looking at the 3.5 CTP for DNOA, I was able to get the ASP.NET sample working.

But I'm lost about how to convert it to work in MVC3.

I tried the naïve approach and moved the sample code from FacebookClient.cs into a small assembly that I call from a controller action, but it dies here:

```
client.RequestUserAuthorization();
```

due to the fact that the HTTP headers have already been returned and cannot be re-written.

So I tried modifying this call to return an action result:

```
return client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization().AsActionResult();
```

But this fails as it forces the browser to try and download something from facebook.

Does anybody have any advice on how I can get my MVC3 app to authenticate against facebook?  I really wish DotNetOpenAuth's CTP included an MVC sample of OAuth2 authentication; I see a LOT of people banging their head against this.  Andrew, save us!

Comment: :) I'm glad you figured something out.  However I'll take that feedback and work out a sample OAuth 2 client for MVC, hopefully in the next CTP/release of DNOA.

Comment: That would be fantastic, Andrew.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Hey Andrew, is there any ETA on that code sample with MVC?! thx

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... things seemt to be working better now, using this:

```
fbClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization().Send();
```

It seems like FB may have been tweaking things on their end, but I am not sure.

Comment: I encounter the same problem and this doesn't resolve it. Do you have any hints ?

Comment: Hey TimH, now that your code works, I'd be curious to see it if you dont mind.